# Export RSAParameters to human readable format

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I have my RSA public key defined in XML file

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>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</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Here is my method where I'm getting the RSA from XML file:

```
        using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            var xml = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(keyConfig.File);
            RSAExtensions.FromXmlString(rsa, xml);

            var paremeters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

            var modulus = paremeters.Modulus;

        }
```

At this moment it works. 
But I have not idea how to convert modulus to e.g string? Modulus is a byte array but when I'm trying to convert this using Encoding.... it returns strange values. How is the modulus represented in this byte array? What format is it?

Comment: "What format is it?" An unsigned, big-endian, big integer.  For every byte except the first one and last one there's a 1/256 chance it is 0, which annoys text encodings.  (And lots of other values also make text encodings upset, but zero is the easiest one to talk about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value can't be converted directly to a string, but it can be represented by a Base64 string:

```
var myString = Convert.ToBase64String(modulus);
```

This will return a string that can later be decoded to get the original binary data.

Comment: You're right. But could you tell me, why it must be converted to base64 first? I will accept your's answer but I must wait about 5 minutes :)

Comment: It's because the data contains non-printable characters, as you noticed when you tried converting it directly to a string. Base64 is a way to represent binary (non-printable) data as ASCII, or printable text.